# how do I get the first word regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to figure out this:

```
This is some text 1
This is some text 2
This is some awesome text
Test!
Test!
This is some text 3
This is some text 4
This is some awesome text
```

Here's some lines of text, I'm trying to get everything from "This is some text 1" all the way down to the first "Test!" But I keep getting it to the second "Test!". How can I make it only capture the first "Test!" ?

Here's what I did:

```
(.*)(Test!)
```

Basically getting everything and then stopping at Test! (Thought first I stopped at the first one)
Then I tried:

```
(.*)(Test!)[\f\r\t\n]
```

Still got the second one I just included everything else
Then I tried:

```
(.*)(Test!){1}
```

Thought that I would get the first one and only that one.

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We will be happy to help you, but this isn't a code service; you have to explain what you already tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @HalayemAnis I tried to get everything first (.*) and then stop at (Test!){1}

Comment: I've edited the question, sorry again!

Comment: Use the _non-greedy_ version.

Comment: Welcome to the stack E.Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is greedy, meaning it matches for as long as possible. Use `?` to make non-greedy:

```
(.+?)Test!
   ^ make it non-greedy
```

[Stub](https://regex101.com/r/eQ2rC7/1). Don't forget the `s` option to make `.` matches newline.

Comment: Nice answer and explanation.